# Unable to handle multiple clients with threadpool as it is suspending the first thread as and when i got the second client request

Tags: java

hi to all i have created a server class with threadpool as shown below and it makes use of workerRunnable class . the problem i am facing with this code is when i am trying to send files from two cliensts at same time  to this server,it is giving me a irregular response (in the sense first thread wil run till next client request is made as soon as the request cums from the second client it stops the first one and starts working on the second req and second one response is sent to both the clients sockets instead of sending their respective response)...pls can any one tell me where i am going wrong?????

```
package com.tel.snmp;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ThreadPooledServer implements Runnable{


    protected int          serverPort   = 4444;//hk
    protected ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    protected boolean      isStopped    = false;
    protected Thread       runningThread= null;
    public BlockingQueue q = new ArrayBlockingQueue(20);
    public static int clientconnection = 0;


    ThreadPoolExecutor threadpool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(4,10,20,TimeUnit.SECONDS,q);

    public ThreadPooledServer(int port){
         this.serverPort = port; // wrk2
           }

    public void run()
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
        }
        openServerSocket();
        while(! isStopped()){
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            try 
            {
                 //System.out.println("the value of client connection BEFORE  is"+clientconnection);

                clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
                clientconnection++;
                System.out.println("the value of client connection is"+clientconnection);
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                if(isStopped()) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Server Stopped.") ;
                    return;
                }
                throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Error accepting client connection", e);
            }
          this.threadpool.execute(new WorkerRunnable(clientSocket,"Thread pooled server")); 

        }
        System.out.println("Server Stopped.") ;
    }


    private synchronized boolean isStopped() {
        return this.isStopped;
    }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        this.isStopped = true;
        try {
            this.serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
        }
    }

    private void openServerSocket() {
        try {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.serverPort); //wrkr2
                     } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open port serverPort"+serverPort, e);
        }
    }
}
-----------------------------Worker Runnable class-----------------------------
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package com.tel.snmp;

/**
 *
 * @author harikrishnadv
 */
import com.tel.common.ProtocolSelector;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


/*public class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable{

    protected Socket clientSocket = null;
    protected String serverText   = null;

    public WorkerRunnable(Socket clientSocket, String serverText) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.serverText   = serverText;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            InputStream input  = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream output = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            output.write(("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\nWorkerRunnable: " +
                    this.serverText + " - " +
                    time +
                    "").getBytes());
            output.close();
            input.close();
            System.out.println("Request processed: " + time);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //report exception somewhere.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
*/
public class WorkerRunnable  implements Runnable
{
    FileInputStream fis;
 FileOutputStream fos;
 BufferedInputStream bis;
 BufferedOutputStream bos;
        String filename="clientfile";
        String fname=null;
 //Socket soc;
        int flag=0;
 int ch;
        //static int count=0;// new
    protected Socket clientSocket = null;
    protected String serverText   = null;

    public WorkerRunnable(Socket clientSocket, String serverText) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.serverText   = serverText;

    }

   public synchronized  void  run() {
  try {
   receiveFile();
                       /*try{
                             this.wait();
                        }
                       catch(InterruptedException i)
                       {

                       }*/
                     if(flag==1)
                        {  
                         System.out.println("**********************************************************************************************************************************");
                         sendFile();                        
                        }
                      closeAll();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

        /** Method to send the response file to the client */
 public void sendFile() throws IOException {
  // SENDING A FILE
                //String sendfile=EMS.fileprocessname+EMS.clientcount+".xml";
                String sendfile=EM.fileprocessname;//+EM.clientcount;
                System.out.println("filename that has been sending to client is"+sendfile);
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());  
                //fis = new FileInputStream("C://outputs.xml");
                fis = new FileInputStream(sendfile);
  while ((ch = fis.read()) != -1) {
   bos.write(ch);
   bos.flush();
  }
  bos.write(-1);
  bos.flush();

  System.out.println("File Sent to :: " + clientSocket);
  fis.close();               
 }

 /** Method to receive input file from client */
        public void receiveFile() throws IOException {
  // RECEIVING A FILE
                 fname="C://"+filename+ThreadPooledServer.clientconnection+".xml";
  bis = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());  
                //fos = new FileOutputStream("C://client.xml");
                fos = new FileOutputStream(fname);
  while ((ch = bis.read()) != 255) {
   fos.write(ch);
   fos.flush();
  }
  System.out.println("File Received from :: " +clientSocket);
  fos.close();

                if(flag==0){
                    ProtocolSelector m=new ProtocolSelector();                
                    //m.xmldecider("C://client.xml");

                    m.xmldecider(fname);
                    flag=1;                                
                }
 }

 public void closeAll() throws IOException {
  bis.close();
  bos.close();
 }
}
```

i wil be thankful for ur valuable reply's

Answer (score 1):

Your `clientconnection` field is static but is then accessed from your `WorkerRunnable receiveFile()` method. By the time the `receiveFile()` method executes there is no guarantee that the value of `clientconnection` is still correct - another client might have come along and incremented it.

Try changing your `WorkerRunnable` constructor to take the `clientconnection` as an argument e.g.

Change:

```
this.threadpool.execute(new WorkerRunnable(clientSocket,
    "Thread pooled server"));
```

to:

```
this.threadpool.execute(new WorkerRunnable(clientSocket, clientconnection, 
    "Thread pooled server"));
```

Add a `clientconnection` field to your `WorkerRunnable` and then change this line:

```
fname="C://"+filename+ThreadPooledServer.clientconnection+".xml";
```

to:

```
fname="C://"+filename+clientconnection+".xml";
```

Comment: thank u .....ya u right as u have said it is getting changed in the mean time when a request is made.....but still i am facing the problem ....can find that anywhere else i am going wrong in the code...and thanks for ur previous reply

Comment: That clientconnection bug would explain why both clients receive the same response. Can you update your question with some details of what you're seeing now?